# Changing user preferences via console?

Tags: scripting, customization

The machine that I'm currently using is an extremely slow netbook. Whenever I go to change user preferences in Blender, it stalls out. What I need to do is activate the "emulate 3 button mouse" checkbox. Is there a way to do this via console/script?

Comment: try experimenting with `bpy.context.user_preferences`, use Ctrl + Space to autocomplete..

Comment: If your computer has problems with the 'preferences' menu, how does it manage rendering?

Comment: @Gwenn it can do it, but pretty slowly. It can even do Cycles. I'm not sure why the preferences menu doesn't work on it.

Comment: If you open the user preferences in a new window, that might slow down a netbook. Instead, try opening the user preferences in the 3dview. And to make sure nothing slows unnecessarily down: don't render in new window or fullscreen, but in existing image editor (make it small).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Got it.

```
bpy.context.user_preferences.inputs.use_mouse_emulate_3_button = True
```

It also says on the [wiki](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_59_0/info_quickstart.html) that The Blender API can modify user preferences, keymaps and themes