# User preferences lags Blender

Tags: customization

Whenever I open up the user preferences tab, it always makes blender glitch, and I have to re-open blender. This might be because I have an old computer (windows vista) or it might be something else that I am not aware of. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/283/599. What are your machine's specs?

Comment: Here is a link to my computer specs:http://www.pcworld.com/product/31104/dell-inspiron-1525.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This usually happens on lower end machines. One fix is to open the preferences view in an already open window (such as the 3d view or timeline) instead of creating one via the *File* menu.