# User Preferences Appearing with Screen Tearing

Tags: interface, customization, error

I downloaded Blender and tried to open User Preferences, but it appears with screen tearing.

Here is a screenshot

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Artifacts like shown one generally mean that something wrong is with graphic driver, either it's not updated or not supported. It doesn't seem to be possible to tell more without more technical information. You can edit the question stating your graphic card model, drivers updated / not, CPU, RAM, operational system etc

Comment: Does opening prefs as suggested in related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16285/user-preferences-lags-blender work?

Comment: @Mr Zak im updating drivers. thx for help