# How do I access a property in the Preferences in 2.80 with Python?

Tags: python, scripting, properties

I want to place a shortcut in the panel I'm creating for changing the **F-curves Default Interpolation Type** found in *Preferences> Animation> F-Curves*.

I have the Python Tooltips enabled and it says:

```
PreferencesEdit.keyframe_new_interpolation_type
```

How do I write a script to access this operator with its functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access that *Preferences* property with the following code:

```
bpy.context.preferences.edit.keyframe_new_interpolation_type
```

To use this in a panel:

```
    row.prop(context.preferences.edit, "keyframe_new_interpolation_type")
```

The full code (using the *UI Panel Simple* template found in the *Text Editor> Templates* menu):

```
import bpy

class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "object"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(context.preferences.edit, "keyframe_new_interpolation_type")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(HelloWorldPanel)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Which displays like this, in the *Object* tab of the *Properties Editor*:

[image]

If you need to set this value manually you can see the list of strings this property expects to be set to in the Blender [2.80 Python API](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.80/bpy.types.PreferencesEdit.html?#bpy.types.PreferencesEdit.keyframe_new_interpolation_type).

Comment: Oh my word! It works and it was so simple. How did you find it?

Comment: I looked up how to access the User Preferences in 2.79 [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/283/changing-user-preferences-via-console), typed `bpy.context.preferences` (as 2.80 has 'Preferences' instead of 'User Preferences') in Blender's *Python Console* and used *Autocomplete* to display the various options.

Comment: This helped so much. Thank you.